# How do you create a Sprint Work Item in the Scrum Template in TFS/Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, scrum

[This page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaronbjork/archive/2010/07/19/announcing-microsoft-visual-studio-scrum-1-0.aspx) talks about a Sprint Work Item in the Scrum Template in TFS/VS2010.

However, I cannot figure out how to create a Sprint Work Item.  What is the menu option I'm supposed to click?  Where do I find this Sprint Work Item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top Menu -> Team -> New Work Item -> Task

You have to be connected to a TFS Server to see the menu (Use the Team Explorer window to do this).

Answer (score 12):

With the latest version of TFS you can add a Sprint as follows:

- Click the Settings 'cog' in the top-right corner of the screen
- Click Iterations tab
- Select the parent level that you wish to add the Sprint to
- Click New Child and add the Sprint name as you wish

Comment: Whoa!!! thank you. Without your help I would have never gotten a sprint done. Most clunky UI ever. In the end though, I hope it's better than Jira

Comment: Not a problem. It's funny that you mention Jira though as we're actually moving from TFS to Jira at work within the next month!

Comment: It's taken me a while to learn how to use it .. but I think it is better than Jira now. Yay me. Would be interesting to hear what you think of Jira once you've used it.

Answer (score -14):

I suggest that you use [Urban Turtle](http://urbanturtle.com). It adds a web client to the TFS Scrum template.  Adding or editing the sprint work item is very easy with Urban Turte. According to Microsoft, the premier Agile tooling for TFS is Urban Turtle. Discloser: I work with the Urban Turtle team. So do not take my words. Instead, read what Brian Harry, who is the Product Unit Manager for Team Foundation Server, said about Urban Turtle: **"...awesome Scrum experience for TFS."** You can read Brian Harry's blog post [here](http://urbanturtle.com/awesome)